# Converting each pixel color of a image into json

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I convert each pixel color from an image into a json file.
For example I have this 352x240 (240p) image of Mario and I wont to grab each pixel in this photo, get its rgb value and then add it to a json file from left to right, top to bottom.

[image]

(I think you have to loop through each pixel of the image, how do you achieve this?)

Like this: (**Variable I have to make so I can use the requirement fs to save the file.**)

```
    data: 
    [
        "0, 0, 0",
        "0, 0, 5"
    ]
};
```

After saved it should look like this: (**String**)

```
{"data":["0, 0, 0","0, 0, 5"]}
```

My code at the moment:

```
var getPixels = require("get-pixels")
var Jimp = require('jimp');
const fs = require("fs");

Jimp.read("240p.png", function (err, image) {
    var imgg = image.getPixelColor(1, 1); // For example I want to get pixel 1,1
    var imgg2 = Jimp.intToRGBA(imgg);

});

var obj = {
    data: 
    [
        "0, 0, 0",
        "0, 0, 5"
    ]
};
var filestring = JSON.stringify(obj);
var filename = "eek"
var file = filename
fs.access(file, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Creating file.")
        fs.writeFile(filename, filestring, 'utf8', function (err){
            if (err) {
                return console.log("Something wen't wrong saving the file.")
            }
            console.log("File was successfully saved.")
        });
        return
    }
    console.log("File already exists.")
})
```

Sources: [get-pixels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-pixels) (Gets image size)
[jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) (Gets pixel color)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my first time working with image using Nodejs. This uses another npm package [pngjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs). Hope that this can help you achieve what you are trying to do !

```js
var PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;
var fs = require("fs");

fs.createReadStream('240p.png').pipe(new PNG({ filterType: 4 })).on('parsed', () => {
    var pixels = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
            var idx = (this.width * y + x) << 2;
            var r = this.data[idx];
            var g = this.data[idx + 1];
            var b = this.data[idx + 2];
            pixels.push(`${r}, ${g}, ${b}`);
        }
    }
    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify({ data: pixels }), 'utf8', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    });
});
```

## Update (11/10/2019)

After some study on using Jimp, I've manage to make it work without using [pngjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs) package. This should output a JSON with correct RGB data !

```js
var Jimp = require("Jimp");
var fs = require("fs");

Jimp.read("240p.png")
  .then(image => {
    var width = image.bitmap.width;
    var height = image.bitmap.height;
    var pixels = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        var pixel = Jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x, y));
        pixels.push(`${pixel.r}, ${pixel.g}, ${pixel.b}`);
      }
    }
    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify({ data: pixels }), 'utf8', (err) => {
        if (err) { throw err; }
    });
  })
  .catch(err => { throw err; });
```

## Update 2 (11/10/2019)

After a lot of trial and error, I've finally came out a working script that converts a png file to a two-dimensional rgb array, and converts two-dimensional rgb array back to png image !
Also note that I am assuming you are trying to save the rgb data as two-dimensional array as it's very important because we have to know the image size based on the array length.

```js
var Jimp = require('Jimp');
var fs = require('fs');

// Create two-dimensional pixels rgb array based on png image
Jimp.read('240p.png')
  .then(image => {
    var width = image.bitmap.width;
    var height = image.bitmap.height;
    var pixels = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      var rowPixels = [];
      for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        var pixel = Jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(x, y));
        rowPixels.push(`${pixel.r}, ${pixel.g}, ${pixel.b}`);
      }
      pixels.push(rowPixels);
    }
    fs.writeFile('INPUT_DATA.json', JSON.stringify({ data: pixels }), 'utf8', err => {
        if (err) { throw err; }
      }
    );
  })
  .catch(err => { throw err; });

// Create png image based on two-dimensional pixels rgb array
fs.readFile('INPUT_DATA.json', 'utf8', (err, file) => {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    var pixelsData = JSON.parse(file);
    var pixels = pixelsData.data;
    new Jimp(pixels[0].length, pixels.length, (err, image) => {
        if (err) { throw err; }
        pixels.forEach((rowPixels, y) => {
            rowPixels.forEach((pixel, x) => {
                var rgb = pixel.split(',');
                var r = Number(rgb[0]);
                var g = Number(rgb[1]);
                var b = Number(rgb[2]);
                var color = Jimp.rgbaToInt(r, g, b, 255);
                image.setPixelColor(color, x, y)
            })
        })
        image.write('OUTPUT_IMAGE.png', (err) => {
            if (err) { throw err; }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: I tried your solution but all the JSON file wrote was "{"data":[]}"

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I've added another answer using `Jimp` npm package.

Comment: I'm going to try to use my script that converts this json into pixels, if it works I cannot thank you enough, I've been trying to do my own solution for so long and you came to help :)

Comment: I've added a complete script that converts from png to two-dimensional rgb array and vice versa. I've learned a lot throughout the process too haha. Hope that this helps you :)